# Registering a new identifier on developer.apple denotes that bundle identifier is "invalid"

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

So, I am trying to publish my Xamarin.Ios app to the app store (really test flight but I have to get an ipa) I'm following along the Microsoft documentation and trying to register a new identifier, however, when I insert my Bundle ID (gotten from info.plist) the web service marks it as "invalid identifier". I've been looking to see if I glanced over a pre-requisite in the documentation but I haven't noticed anything. Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Hi, you could have a check with [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/). And which type of Apple ID you are using?

Comment: Thank you for the response. I've enrolled in the Apple developer program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I had an underscore in my bundle id and that was the issue, ostensibly changing it to ascii code will fix the issue. However, I'm unsure of how to change it exactly, for instance, _ is 95 using ascii code but if I have blah_app and change it to blah95app that would allow me to register but I'm not sure if that is in the correct format.